# Maven dependency picocontainer

Tags: maven

I'm trying to include with maven dependency for

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jacorb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacorb</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Dependency is resolved, but it's causing problem with another dependency, picocontainer:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project s_s: Could not resolve dependencies 
for project my.package:s_s:war:1: Failed to collect dependencies for  org.jacorb:jacorb:jar:2.3.1 (compile), picocontainer:picocontainer:jar:1.2 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for picocontainer:picocontainer:jar:${picocontainer.version}: Could not transfer artifact picocontainer:picocontainer:pom:${picocontainer.version} from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 65: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/picocontainer/picocontainer/${picocontainer.version}/picocontainer-${picocontainer.version}.pom -> [Help 1]
```

When I check local repo, version named `${picocontainer.version}` is created. I've tried include own dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>picocontainer</groupId>
    <artifactId>picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

But it's not helping, could someone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I figured it out :) I ought to exclude dependency from `org.jacorb` like this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.jacorb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacorb</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>picocontainer</groupId>
                <artifactId>picocontainer</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>picocontainer</groupId>
                <artifactId>picocontainer-tck</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>picocontainer</groupId>
                <artifactId>picocontainer-gems</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

And include necessary one

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>picocontainer</groupId>
        <artifactId>picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>picocontainer</groupId>
        <artifactId>picocontainer-tck</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>picocontainer</groupId>
        <artifactId>picocontainer-gems</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I guess it's maven corrupted artifact?